# Selenium Select Element By Class

Tags: c#, facebook, selenium

I want to Select An element using Selenium C#.. the element changes it's ID on each page refresh.. but the class remains the same.

```
<button value="1" class="_42ft _4jy0 PageLikeButton _4jy4 _517h _9c6" data-profileid="410450525803083" data-ownerid="u_0_38" id="u_0_39" type="submit"><i class="_3-8_ img sp_j8Y25-Vyqxr sx_9b87dd"></i>Like</button>
```

the id is *u_0_39*

I used to use this code:

```
IWebElement likepage = firefox.FindElement(By.Id("u_0_1k"));
likepage.Click();
```

but now the ID is changing on each page refresh while the class remains the same

```
class="_42ft _4jy0 PageLikeButton _4jy4 _517h _9c6"
```

I want to use Selenium C# to select this element by class not ID as the id is changing .. and click it
Like Facebook page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not depend on the class itself since the class look more generic as well. I would think the `xpath` is the best fit here with text based search

```
By byXpath = By.Xpath("//button[contains(.,'Like')]");
IWebElement likepage = firefox.FindElement(byXpath);
likepage.Click();
```